# How do I configure plug to set another directory as public other than priv/static/?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently using aurelia as my front end framework for my phoenix app. I would like to designate the jspm_packages folder in the root of my project as a static directory in addition to the priv/static folder. Is there a way to configure plug to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: you should not.

The long answer is: in production, Elixir applications care about two directories: 1. ebin (which is where you put compiled code) and 2. priv (auxiliary files that you need to run your software in production, like static files). If you rely on a file that is not in any of those directories, things can break when running in production or building releases. So I would advise you to move the aurelia stuff inside priv/static or have a tool that compiles aurelia artifacts to priv/static at the end of the day.

If you don't want to do that, the "I have warned you" alternative is here: http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html. You can set `from: "."` when configuring `Plug.Static` in your Phoenix endpoint at `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex`. You can also plug more than one `Plug.Static` if you want.

Comment: @Korbin Setting a symlink of aurelia root directory to priv/static - will that help?

Comment: I think I'm going to follow Jose's advice and not change it. I'm just pointing the jspm packages to a directory inside of the priv/static folder.

Comment: For those like me who wanted to *add* another repository to the static ones, what worked for me is to use the `CopyWebpackPlugin` in my webpack config to make sure it goes to `priv/static` in the end: `new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'path_to_repository', to: '..' }])`